How to insert information from a exec procedure 'parameter' that finishes with different selects corresponding to this 'parameter'
I have a procedure that gets data from different tables and processes it using different parameters and instructions. At that end of that procedure, it executes different selects corresponding to one of the parameters which I'll call 'parameter'. A single 'parameter' returns a single SELECT. These selects are all different from each other. as in
'parameter1'
select col 1, col 3, col 7 from #proctemp

'parameter2'
select col 2, col 3, col 5 from #proctemp

and so on. I need to have this information on a #temp using something of the form of
insert into #temp
    exec procedure 'parameter'

Here comes the problem: from my understanding, to execute this properly, it's necessary to create the table beforehand which is a problem considering the layout will change for different parameters.
I don't have access to openrowset and I can't modify the procedure that runs these different selects from the #proctemp.
I've tried to get the metadata in some form to execute a dynamic create table option which doesn't seem to be viable considering the #proctemp itself isn't what is selected, what's selected are specific columns from this table.
I've unsuccessfully tried to have a temp table for all possible columns that fills in nulls when that specific column isn't being selected, and fills the remaining columns in the correct order.
The parameters that define which columns are selected are not that many, so I've also thought about creating each specific layout with an if check for the parameter which my boss blocked me from doing.

"considering the layout will change for different [sic] parameters" This sounds like the (real* problem. If you do need to INSERT your data into a table, then you should be ensuring the data is returned in a consistent format.

When you call the proc with 'parameter' you already know the table layout you expect, so it's only the matter of creating the table beforehand. If you can't do that, how do you process the output of the insert/exec since you don't know what it will be. Although, in my opinion insert/exec is an antipattern which is like a canary that points to issues. I much prefer the procedure to populate the output tables
